# Extracting Client ID as a custom dimension with audience dimensions through API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

I'm looking to get some answers here regarding the matter. There is no formal documentation available, would like some answers to my dilemma. Currently on analytics, I have Client ID setup as a custom dimension, session scope, I'm currently trying to match this Client ID with other dimensions via the Analytics Reporting API v4. (Reason having done so is that because in order for Client ID to be available outside of User Explorer on Analytics, one has to setup a custom dimension for this)

It's come to my attention that when I try to match Client ID, with an Audience Dimension, such as Affinity, nothing comes up. But say I do so with another dimension like PagePath + Affinity, the table exist. So I know that it is possible to pull Audience dimensions with other dimensions and it's possible for me to pull Client ID together with other dimensions. But what I'm trying to understand is why can't I pull Client ID together with Audience dimensions?

Some clarification on the matter would truly be appreciated, thanks.

For example (Can't show everything, but this is the response body of the python script)

In the case that i try to match my custom dimension (Client ID, session scope) with Affinity.

```
    request_report = {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'pageSize' : 100000,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-12-14',
                      'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}
                  ],
       'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dateHour'},
                      {'name':'ga:dimension1'},
                      {'name': 'ga:interestAffinityCategory'}                      
                      ]        
    }

response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': request_report

      }).execute()
```

Output:

```
    ga:dateHour ga:dimension1   ga:interestAffinityCategory ga:users
```

Changing my dimensions, to pagePath + Affinity

```
    request_report = {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'pageSize' : 100000,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-12-14',
                      'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}
                  ],
       'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dateHour'},
                      {'name': 'ga:pagePath'},
                      {'name': 'ga:interestAffinityCategory'}                      
                      ]        
    }

response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': request_report

      }).execute()
```

Output:

```
ga:dateHour ga:pagePath   ga:interestAffinityCategory   ga:users
2018121415  homepage      Business Professionals        10
2019011715  join-beta     Beauty Mavens                 16
2019011715  join-beta     Frequently Visits Salons      21
```

Now say I change my combination to custom dimension + device category

```
    request_report = {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'pageSize' : 100000,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-12-14',
                      'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}
                  ],
       'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dateHour'},
                      {'name': 'ga:adContent'},
                      {'name': 'ga:deviceCategory'}                      
                      ]        
    }

response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': request_report

      }).execute()
```

Output:

```
ga:dateHour ga:dimension1   ga:adContent    ga:deviceCategory   ga:users
2018121410  10              ad1             desktop             1
2018121410  111             ad1             mobile              1
2018121410  119             ad4             mobile              1
2018121410  15              ad3             desktop             1
2018121410  157             ad3             mobile              1
```

In conclusion:
What I'd like to achieve is being able to pair my custom dimensions (Client ID) together with audience dimensions in order to be able to do segmentations. But first things first, if this permutation is not possible, I would like to understand as to why it's not possible? Is this a limitation from the API side? Or is this a policy thing (taking a guess here as I understand that there are identity protection policies)?

Comment: Welcome to stack.  Please edit your question.  Include your code.  and describe any issues you are having with that code.   Unless you sent your custom dimension with every hit request that came to your site then you are not going to be able to analyse on it.

Comment: @DaImTo Hi, i apologise for the delay in response, I have added snippets of my python script as above, my issue isn't with the code, but it's more of my lack of understanding in possible permutations. What I am understanding from your statement above is that because my custom dimension is a session scope dimension, I am unable to pull it with other dimensions? But my last example shows that I am able to do so, I find that i can't pull client ID with audience dimensions.

Comment: If your not getting databack thats probably due to the fact that the data you are requesting does not exist.  Its not possible to do multi dimension analysis on all dimensions and metrics. this is especially the case when you are talking about custom dimensions.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for the feedback, I understand that the permutation may not exist due to table structures (this i'm not too sure off as i'm not fully aware of the ERD/mapping or how the tables are structured on the google analytics database) or that it may not be possible. What I'm trying to understand is why the custom dimension (Client ID) and Audience dimensions can't be queried, cause unfortunately my boss really isn't the type to accept not possible because it's not possible. There has to be an explanation as to why it's not possible.

Comment: Adding on as an observation on the Analytics platform, on Audience > Interest > Affinity Categories. When I include Client ID as my secondary dimension, it only returns Affinity where Client ID is false (which means failure to capture Client ID from GTM)

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery integration does not contain demographics/affinitys. The User Interface contains a variety of mechanisms to prevent you from isolating individual users, so in short no.